# find vs querySelector AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, find

I use AngularJS and I get error when I use querySelector

```
angular.element(angular.element(e).querySelector('.open')).removeClass('open');
```

And if I use

```
angular.element(angular.element(e).find('.open')).removeClass('open');
```

Works without problems.

The error:

**TypeError: angular.element(...).querySelector is not a function**

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector` is not an Angular function. That is a raw JavaScript [document function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which could be used on a raw DOM element.

So, given that information here's how you might modify your code to get the same result:

```
angular.element(angular.element(e)[0].querySelector('.open')).removeClass('open');
```

Answer (score 0):

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) is the method of the DOM Element, not `angular.element` ([jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)).

In order to use querySelector with jqLite instance you need to get raw HTMLElement first:

```
angular.element(angular.element(e)[0].querySelector('.open')).removeClass('open');
```

`angular.element(e)` is an [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) instance, which is array-like object of HTMLElement. You can access individual HTMLElements by their index, that's why you use something like `angular.element(e)[0]`.